# What does "be composed entirely out of A and B" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Does it mean being composed of "both A and B" or "neither A nor B" or anything else?

Where to affect "out"?

My concern is this sentence:

> A combinator (or supercombinator) is a function which is composed entirely out of bound variables and other (super)combinators.
>   [A Gentle Introduction to Parsec ¶ blog.barrucadu](http://blog.barrucadu.co.uk/2013/05/27/a-gentle-introduction-to-parsec/)

(p.s. I would appreciate it if you could correct my poor English)

Comment: You may find [ell.se] helpful.

Comment: I did not notice such a service running ! I gonna try to use next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that it is entirely made from.

Example:  Water is composed entirely out of hydrogen and oxygen.

Comment: Thank you! "entirely" is optional, isn't it? Is "composed out of" an idiom?

Comment: Not really.  Entirely has pertinent meaning in the phrase.  Let's say that water was made of .001% nitrogen.  You could say that water is made of hydrogen and oxygen and hydrogen but not entirely out of oxygen and hydrogen.

Comment: I could grasp the image. I very much appreciate you.

Comment: Hmm... I want to check my understanding. "composed out of" means like "made of", and "entirely" plus shade of meaning like 'exactly'. Right?

Comment: I'm more familiar with 'Water is composed entirely of hydrogen and oxygen.' [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=composed+entirely+of%2Ccomposed+entirely+out+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) and 'Water is composed of hydrogen and oxygen.' [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=composed+of%2Ccomposed+out+of%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - That sounds a bit better but I hear both.

Comment: To me(English Language Lerner), 'out' in the sentence sounds like having negative meaning. How to consider about 'out'?

Comment: @ggkuron - out is often used to replace "of" in these circumstances.  I understand that it can be confusing but that is just the usage.

Comment: @RyeBread I am trying to be accustomed to that usage of 'out'. Thank you!